# 500 Internal Server Error on POST call to /index.html in Angular application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, internal-server-error

I'm working on an angular application. I'm facing this issue, and I need some help solve it.

When I perform a GET operation on http://<myapp>/index.html, it works fine.
When I perform a POST operation on http://<myapp>/index.html, it returns `500 Internal Server Error` with no content in the response body or header.

I looked into `RouterModule.forRoot` in `app.module.ts` but couldn't find any option to filter out `POST` call alone.

This is an Asp.Net Core MVC application that I'm running.

I'm new to angular. I'm not sure which path to follow. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to `POST` to `/index.html`?

Comment: well, frankly, its not me. Its an automated polling system POSTing to my app. This is bringing down the reliability score of my application. Hence, trying to get rid of this.

Comment: Can you show your view and both actions - for get and post , pls?

Comment: Try to set break point in the Post method and check whether this method is executed and step by step to check if there have any error or exception. Generally, in the angular application, we are using the [Event binding](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding) to handle the post action. Besides, as Serge said, it is better to share the relates code to reproduce the problem, then, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I recently got into the same issue and from my investigation the code is behaving differently depending on the environment (Development vs Production )
On the development if you do a POST to /index.html you get 404, on production you get 500. I also raised a GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34420

My temporary solution was to add a middleware and catch the exception coming from UseSpa middleware

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ......
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        //Redirect to root request to /index.html ( except the GET request ) 
        //Do not generate logs for requests originating from automated tools: POST /Index.html, OPTIONS /index.html, DEBUG /index.htm, etc.. 
        if (!HttpMethods.IsGet(context.Request?.Method)
            && context.Request?.Path.Value.ToLower() == "/index.html")
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            await next();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException spaException)
        {
            if (spaException.Message.StartsWith("The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page"))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
                return;
            }
            throw;
        }
    });

    app.UseSpa(...);
    .....
}
```